# PHP Strtotime 5th day last month

Tags: php, strtotime

How can I use `strtotime()` to find midnight of the fifth day of last month? I know the first day can be found using`strtotime('midnight first day of last month');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a combination of statements to get there. `DateTime()` is well suited for that as you can chain methods (and it's readable, too):

```
$timestamp = (new DateTime('midnight first day of last month'))->modify('+5 days')->getTimestamp();
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/372055)

Comment: Just so you know this will return a date time 2015-05-28 12:12:12 like so. strtotime returns seconds

Comment: @khuderm [`getTimestamp()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) will return a UNIX timestamp, which is in seconds.

Comment: I ended up having to use $date = new DateTime('midnight first day of last month'); $timestamp = $date->modify('+14 days')->getTimestamp(); cause I'm not on 5.4

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime('midnight first day of last month') + (60*60*24*5);
```

either try `*5` or `*4` and read up on `strtotime`.

`strtotime` is in seconds so you can just add however many days you want to it in seconds.